# realloc(): invalid next size after two computations

Tags: c, function, malloc, structure, realloc

I created the structure to store an array of digits. The array is dynamically allocated. The problem occurs when trying to reallocate some space in function. The error is

```
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The structure is as follows

```
typedef struct big_number {
    unsigned int *digits;
    int num_of_digits;
}BigNumber;
```

The function looks like this (multiplies digit with BigNumber):

```
void scale(BigNumber a, int c, BigNumber* scaled)
{
    scaled->num_of_digits = a.num_of_digits;
    scaled->digits = NULL;
    scaled->digits = malloc(scaled->num_of_digits * sizeof (unsigned int));

    if (scaled->digits == NULL) {
        error();
    }

    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = scaled->num_of_digits; i >= 0; i--) {
        int tmp = a.digits[i] * c + carry;
        scaled->digits[i] = tmp % 10;
        carry = tmp / 10;
    }

    if (carry != 0) {
        //While trying realloc in this line problem occurs
        scaled->num_of_digits += 1;
        scaled->digits = realloc(scaled->digits, scaled->num_of_digits * sizeof (unsigned int));
        scaled->digits[0] = carry;
    }
}
```

The calls in main look like this:

```
    printf("Results:\n");

    scale(num_b, 5, &pomocna);
    print_big_number(pomocna);
    free(pomocna.digits);
```

Comment: `realloc` should be always assigned to an intermediate pointer variable, and not the same one being reallocated for the error case handling (which you are not doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays go from `0` to `n-1`. You are writing to `array[n]` which does not exist

```
scaled->digits = malloc(scaled->num_of_digits * sizeof (unsigned int));
for (int i = scaled->num_of_digits; i >= 0; i--) { // AAA
        int tmp = a.digits[i] * c + carry;
        scaled->digits[i] = tmp % 10;             // BBB
```

In line AAA you set `i` to the size of array (to `n`)

In line BBB you try to change `scaled->digits[i]` (`array[n]`)

Comment: This solved the problem, I did not notice the mistake with indexes of array. Thanks.